# Combine List<Observable<String>> into Observable<List<String>>

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I have the following example:

```
val strings: List<Observable<String>> = listOf(
                Observable.just("One"),
                Observable.just("Two"),
                Observable.just("Three")
        )
```

I tried to use `combineLatest`, `zip`, `merge` to convert the above `strings` into the following but I failed:

```
val convertedStrings: Observable<List<String>> = strings.xxxx()
```

Is there RxJava-approach to achieve the above conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Single<List<String>> list = Observable.concat(strings).toList();
```

?

(There is also a chance that you are looking for `concatEager`.)